# I am trying to understand Multiple Inheritance of methods in Python 3 OOPS through a self-created example, but am getting various errors

Tags: oop, inheritance, methods

```
class P1:
    def __init__ (self, Q1):
        self.Q1 = Q1

    def Proc1 (self, I1):
        self.I1 = I1
        R1 = self.Q1 * self.I1
        self.R1 = R1
        print ("Result from Parent 1:", R1)

class P2:
    def __init__ (self, Q2):
        self.Q2 = Q2

    def Proc2 (self, I2):
        self.I2 = I2
        R2 = self.Q2 + self.I2
        self.R2 = R2
        print ("Result from Parent 2:", R2)

class Child0 (P1, P2):
    def __init__ (self, Q1, Q2):
        super().__init__ (self)
        #P2.__init__ (self, Q2)
    
    def Combine (self, A1, A2):
        B1 = 9
        B2 = 10
        print ("Combined result:", P1.Proc1(B1,12) / P2.Proc2(B2, 14))

U1 = Child0 (6, 10)
```

#U1.Proc1(7)
#error msg - unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Child0' and 'int'

#U1.Proc2(8)
#error msg -'Child0' object has no attribute 'Q2' when above line is commented out

#U1.Combine(7,8)
#error msg -'int' object has no attribute 'I1' when U1.Proc1 and U1.Proc2 are commented out

'''
I created two parent classes with a method inside each of them. I then created a Child class that should inherit each of the methods of the parent class to create a new method at the child level. I can call the methods of the parent class independently, but can not call the method of the  child class or the methods of the parent class by initiating an object of the child class.

I would like to understand each of these 3 errors and how to get rid of them
'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're initializing `Child0` right.  You are passing `self` as a variable to one of the other `__init__` methods (I think P1's).

Try this

```
class Child0 (P1, P2):
    def __init__ (self, Q1, Q2):
        self.Q1 = Q1
        self.Q2 = Q2
```

Comment: Sobigen - As a result of your suggestion, I can now run U1.Proc(1 argument), and U1.Proc2(1 argument)  but the last line, U1.Combine ... still shows the same error.

Comment: Within `Combine` you're giving Proc1 and Proc2 two arguments but in the definition it only accepts one.  You don't pass `self` directly.  From within `Combine` you can call `self.Proc1(argument)`  That would be more logical (to me at least) than calling P1.Proc1.  I don't know where you want A1, A2, B1, or B2 to go.

Comment: Sobigen - I changed the Combine invocation to the following:

print ("Combined result:", P1.Proc1(self, B1) / P2.Proc2(self, B2))

 ... so now I am passing the right number of arguments to combine. It invokes Proc1 and Proc2 correctly, but and am getting the error from invoking Combine as follows: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Comment: You're not returning anything from Proc1 or Proc2.  Just printing the result.

Comment: I see what you are hinting at ... I changed the print statement to return statements and now a result is being generated. Thank you for the guidance.